# Remove Validation using Jquery/MVC Forms

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am building an application that has a form where certain elements will hide using `Jquery` if a checkbox is checked as follows:

```
$('#Rebilled').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#RebillDate').show();
        $('#RebillAmount').show();
        $('#TodaysAccountBalance').show();
        $('#BalanceAfterRebill').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#RebillDate').hide();
        $('#RebillAmount').hide();
        $('#TodaysAccountBalance').hide();
        $('#BalanceAfterRebill').hide();
    }
});
```

We are running both Server-Side and Client-Side validation on these fields and we're trying to solve the problem of validation still running on the hidden fields where they are required when not hidden.

I can resolve this in the client side by using `jquery` to remove the validation however once posted to the server the server rejects it because they are required fields that now haven't been filled in due to being hidden causing my `ModelState` to be invalid.

The only way we've been able to resolve this so far is to add a default value to the field as its posted to the server, again, using `jQuery`. Something like:

```
$('#RebillDate').val("01/01/1900")
```

Is this a correct way of doing this or are we missing something more obvious?

Comment: Use conditional validation attributes (which work both client and server side). For example [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]`, or you can easily write your own - [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: This is perfect thank you, are you able to add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: No time now - perhaps later (or feel free to add your own answer and accept it to close this out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Steven Mueckes answer:

Use conditional validation attributes (which work both client and server side). For example foolproof [RequiredIf], or you can easily write your own